# Where is skydrive in outlook.com

Tags: onedrive, windows-live

I used to use Skydrive in live/hotmail.com. The step is login my account then click skydrive tab. But now when I login live/hotmail, it is redirected to outlook.com, I can't find skydrive anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find it without any issues.

Click the White Arrow Here:
[image: Click Me]

Which Displays: [image: Skydrive]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the icon or the down arrow in the upper right. There will be links to Skydrive, Contacts, and Calendar.